# Center and Start text in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

How can I put the text in the center of the total clickable area and still in the start of the component?

Like an android:layout_gravity="center" with margin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart` with Box.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            
        }
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(46.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
) {
    Text("Hello World")
}
```